# Different R versions to build binaries for packages?

Tags: r, package, devtools, building

I’m building R package binaries for windows. I’d like to know if I have to build the package with different versions of R (i.e 3.3, 3.4, 3.5) to share the packages. Or would it be fine to build with one version and send to the repo as ../windows/contrib//...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, you would have to compile against the different R versions that you want to use.

Comment: Or just release it as source and force the user to install from source.